# Adduser command not working in Linux

Tags: command-line, terminal, console, linux-terminal

When I type `adduser -m *username*`, I recieve this from the terminal:

```
bash: adduser: command not found
```

(in spanish `orden no encontrada`)

I tried installing `adduser` but it was already installed.

Comment: Whats flavor of linux are you running?

Comment: I'm using Kali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because its not native to all linux distros, `useradd` is the native command. `adduser` is a user-friendly version that implements Perl:

> Useradd is built-in Linux command that can be found on any Linux
>   system. However, creating new users with this low-level is a tedious
>   task.
>
> Adduser is not a standard Linux command. It’s essentially a Perl
>   script that uses the useradd command in the background. This
>   high-level utility is more efficient in properly creating new users on
>   Linux. Default parameters for all new users can also be set through
>   the adduser command.

Retrieved: https://linuxhandbook.com/useradd-vs-adduser/

**If you are on a Debian based distro (Ubuntu, etc)** you can install it with the folowing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adduser
```

If that doesn't work, check if `useradd` is installed correctly.

**Otherwise, if you are not on a Debian-based system (Redhat, etc)** you probably just want to stick with useradd... I don't think they support `adduser`.

**If you are on a Debian system and the installation doesn't work** you might have an issue with your path variables. You can learn more about this here 
https://youtu.be/Jp0WWDSJ3Ac

Comment: I have Kali Linux, is it already installed there?? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Should be... Im guessing there is an issue with you path variables ... I'm adding a link to my original answer on how to fix the paths.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: I have fixed it with the info you supplied, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If "useradd" is not working, check your PATH variable.
Check for presence of useradd under /usr/sbin/useradd. It should be present by default.

```bash
$ echo PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Assign "/usr/sbin" to the path.

```bash
$ $PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$ export PATH
```

now "useradd" should work.

```bash
$ useradd -help|more
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take on this:

I was working with a container image (`azul/zulu-openjdk` if anyone is interested), where it looked like `/usr/sbin/useradd` really did not exist. `adduser`, however, was present and worked to create the user. Beware though, as it does have slightly different options to the `useradd` command.

e.g.

```
adduser -u <numeric uid> -G <primary group> -D <username>
```

`-D` tells `adduser` not to prompt for password creation after the user is created.